# GitHub Actions for Terraform - How to provide "terraform.tfvars" file with aws credentials

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, github-actions

I am trying to setup GitHub Actions for execute a terraform template.

My confusion is - how do I provide *.tfvars file which has aws credentials. (I can't check-in these files).

**Whats the best practice to share the variable's values expected by terraform commands like plan or apply where they need aws_access_key and aws_secret_key.**

Here is my GitHub project - https://github.com/samtiku/terraform-ec2

Any guidance here...

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide all variables through *.tfvars file. Apart from `-var-file` option, terraform command provides also `-var` parameter, which you can use for passing secrets.

In general, secrets are passed to scripts through environment variables. CI tools give you an option to define environment variables in project configuration. It's a manual step, because as you have already noticed, secrets cannot be stored in the repository.

I haven't used Github Actions in particular, but after setting environment variables, all you need to do is run terraform with secrets read from them:

```sh
$ terraform -var-file=some.tfvars -var "aws-secret=${AWS_SECRET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}
```

This way no secrets are ever stored in the repository code. If you'd like to run terraform locally, you'll need first to export these variables in your shell :

```sh
$ export AWS_SECRET_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE="..."
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Terraform allows providing credentials to some providers via their configuration arguments for flexibility in complex situations, the recommended way to pass credentials to providers is via some method that is standard for the vendor in question.

For AWS in particular, the main standard mechanisms are either [a credentials file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) or via [environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html). If you configure the action to follow what is described in one of those guides then Terraform's AWS provider will automatically find those credentials and use them in the same way that the AWS CLI does.

It sounds like environment variables will be the easier way to go within GitHub actions, in which case you can just set the necessary environment variables directly and the AWS provider should use them automatically. If you are using the S3 state storage backend then it will also automatically use the standard AWS environment variables.

If your system includes multiple AWS accounts then you may wish to review the Terraform documentation guide [Multi-account AWS Architecture](https://www.terraform.io/docs/backends/types/s3.html#multi-account-aws-architecture) for some ideas on how to model that. The summary of what that guide recommends is to have a special account set aside *only* for your AWS users and their associated credentials, and then configure your other accounts to allow cross-account access via roles, and then you can use a single set of credentials to run Terraform but configure each instance of the AWS provider to assume the appropriate role for whatever account that provider instance should interact with.